# Variance of taking balls from a bag question

Tags: probability, random-variables, variance

A bag contains $2$ white balls and $2$ black balls.
Each instance a ball is taken from the bag, if it's white it's returned to the bag and if it's black it's replaced by a white ball. The game ends when no black balls remain in the bag. Let $Y$ be the number of instances of the game; calculate $\operatorname{var}(Y).$ Answer in the book: $14.$

I am not sure how to write the probability function of $Y;$ please help and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Let $Y_1$ be the random variable who value is the number of draws until the first black ball is drawn.  This is a [geometrically-distributed random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) with probability of success $\frac12$.

Similarly, let $Y_2$ be the random variable who value is the number of draws until the second black ball is drawn, after the first black ball is replaced by a white ball.  This is a geometrically-distributed random variable with probability of success $\frac14$.

Then $Y=Y_1+Y_2$.

Take it from here.

Answer (score 0):

Let $Y$ be the number of black balls taken. The probability distribution table:
$$\begin{array}{c|l}
Y&P(Y)\\
\hline
2&\frac1{2^3}\\
3&\frac1{2^4}+\frac3{2^5}\\
4&\frac1{2^5}+\frac3{2^6}+\frac{3^2}{2^7}\\
5&\frac1{2^6}+\frac3{2^7}+\frac{3^2}{2^8}+\frac{3^3}{2^9}\\
\vdots
\end{array}$$
Note:
$$P(Y=n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{3^{i-1}}{2^{n+i}}=\frac13\cdot \frac1{2^n}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(\frac32\right)^i=\frac{2\cdot 3^n-3\cdot 2^n}{3\cdot 4^n}.$$
Hence:
$$Var(Y)=\mathbb E(Y^2)-(\mathbb E(Y))^2=\\
\sum_{i=2}^\infty i^2\cdot \frac{2\cdot 3^i-3\cdot 2^i}{3\cdot 4^i}-\left(\sum_{i=2}^\infty i\cdot \frac{2\cdot 3^i-3\cdot 2^i}{3\cdot 4^i}\right)^2=\\
50-36=14.$$
WA answers: [1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%283%5E%28i-1%29%2F2%5E%28n%2Bi%29%2Ci%3D1..n-1%29), [2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%28k%5E2%282*3%5Ek-3*2%5Ek%29%2F%283*4%5Ek%29%2Ck%3D2..infty%29), [3](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28sum%28k%282*3%5Ek-3*2%5Ek%29%2F%283*4%5Ek%29%2Ck%3D2..infty%29%29%5E2).